# How to dynamically extend class with method in Typescript from remote js file?

Tags: javascript, extends, typescript2.0

I have TypeScript code with classes of components. And I want to use somehow remote js file to extend this classes remote. So I want when my app starts to get js file remote and use code this for extend of needed class.
How to extend class I know. For example:

```
Import { UsersBlocksMyOrders } from "../pages/users/blocks/myorders";

declare module "../pages/users/blocks/myorders" {
    interface UsersBlocksMyOrders {
        logit(): void;
    }
}

UsersBlocksMyOrders.prototype.logit = function () { console.log(this); }
```

In component file the code is:

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from "../../../app/app.config";

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-blocks-menupage',
  templateUrl: APP_CONFIG.appDomain + '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/menu/blocks/menupage'
})

export class MenuBlocksMenuPage{

  constructor(){
    this.logit();
  }
}
```

My problem is that I use the Webpack to compile code. Webpack create final file where name of function is different. That's why I can't access to class directly.

How to be in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create service to get file and extend class. You need to have variable inside class which is would store object where have keys. Keys it is names of classes to extend. And values with imported classes. Inside init function we are loop extending with prototype method.

```js
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { MenuBlocksMenuPage } from "../pages/menu/blocks/menupage";


export class ExtendService {
  allModules = {
    ...
    MenuBlocksMenuPage : MenuBlocksMenuPage,
    ...
  };

  constructor(public http: Http){ }

  init()
  {
    //Load json map to extend class
    this.http.get(APP_CONFIG.appDomain + '/modules/mobilesiteapp/view/js/extend.json').toPromise()
      .then((res) => {
        let json = res.json();

        //Loop each class to extend
        Object.keys(json).forEach((cl) => {
          //Add new functions and methods
          Object.keys(json[cl]).forEach((func) => {
            this.allModules[cl].prototype[func] = eval(json[cl][func]);
          });
        });

      }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }
}
```

2. Request json file with functions to eval.

```js
{
    "MenuBlocksMenuPage": {
        "logit": "(function (){console.log(this);})"
    }
}
```